Auth::user() returns null, but works in the function that Auth::login() called
Laravel does not save my session after auth()->login()
Hello. I'm using Socialite to create Google login in Laravel application, the redirect and callback functions worked fine. But I am having some trouble in login session, Laravel did not save my session after calling Auth::login(), and Auth::user() returns null, but Auth::user() still works in the function (controller action) where Auth::login() called. Can someone help me?
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function callback(Request $request) {
        $googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
        $userLogin = [
            'id' => $googleUser->getId(),
            'name' => $googleUser->getName(),
            'email' => $googleUser->getEmail(),
            'avatar' => $googleUser->getAvatar(),
        ];
        $email = $userLogin['email'];
        $user = User::updateOrCreate(
            ['email' => $email],
            $userLogin
        );
        auth()->login($user);
        // This still working.
        // dd(auth()->user());
        return redirect()->route('debug');
    }
}

But it wasn't work in another controller action
class DebugController extends Controller {
    public function __invoke() {
        $user = auth()->user();
        // This returns null
        dd($user);
    }
}


It seems like the session is not persisting the login. Have you search for answers to similar questions posted on SO? E.g. is your middleware configured correctly as described here?

Yes but all answers in that post are useless

Is that "yes, I've searched" or "yes, the middleware is configured correctly"? Apologies, I should only ask one question at a time.

Yes, I have looked that post sir

Have you configured your middleware to use Auth?

Yep, I wrote my own middleware

I don't mean your own middleware. Can you show the web.php routes file so we can see if it's using the Auth middleware correctly for the debug route.
